# How is OpenMP communicating between threads with what should be a private variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm writing some code in C++ using OpenMP to parallelize some chunks. I run into some strange behavior that I can't quite explain. I've rewritten my code such that it replicates the issue minimally.

First, here is a function I wrote that is to be run in a parallel region.

```
void foo()
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        printf("Hello %d from thread %d.\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Then here is my whole program.

```
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            foo();
            #pragma omp critical
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this code (with g++ -std=c++17), I get the following output on the terminal:

```
Hello 0 from thread 0.
Hello 1 from thread 1.
Hello 2 from thread 2.
0
0
Hello 2 from thread 2.
Hello 1 from thread 1.
0
Hello 0 from thread 0.
0
1
1
1
1
```

`i` is a private variable. I would expect that the function `foo` would be run twice per thread. So I would expect to see eight "Hello from %d thread %d.\n" statements in the terminal, just like how I see eight numbers printed when printing `i`. So what gives here? Why is it that in the same loop, OMP behaves so differently?

Comment: Your outer loop runs twice and the inner three times, `2*3=6` so i don't see why six prints is unexpected?

Comment: @AlanBirtles my question why does that number not depend on the number of threads because each thread should individually be calling function `foo()`. The `printf` statement in `main()` does do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of `omp parallel`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-c-and-cpp-linux/13.1.5?topic=parallelization-pragma-omp-parallel):

> Each thread in the team executes all statements within a parallel region *except for work-sharing constructs*.

Emphasis mine. Since the `omp for` in `foo` is a work-sharing construct, it is only executed once per outer iteration, no matter how many threads run the parallel block in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `#pragma omp for` is a worksharing construct, so it will distribute the work among threads and the number of threads used does not matter in this respect, just the number of loop counts (`2*3=6`).

If you use `omp_set_num_threads(1);` you also see 6 outputps. If you use more threads than loop counts, some threads will be idle in the inner loop, but you still see exactly 6 outputs.

On the other hand, if you remove `#pragma omp for` line you will see `(number of threads)*2*3` (=24) outputs.